# Forcing Groovy to use standard java switch?

Tags: performance, groovy

I have a Groovy **switch** called (very) frequently in my application. *VisualVM* sampling shows that I spend around 20% of my application time in *ScriptBytecodeAdapter.isCase()*.

Since all the cases are strings, my usage would be supported by the standard Java 7 [string switch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html) which should be more efficient.

Is it possible to ask Groovy to fallback to the standard Java switch ?

***Remarks:***

- I can use **AST**s (the switch it self is generated by an AST in SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS).
- Other implementation options could be to use **if**s/**else**s instead (I usually have < 20 cases) or a **Map** of Closures

Comment: Have you tried your other implementation options and profiled them to see if it makes a difference? If those don't help, you might try applying the CompileStatic transformation in your AST transformer (assuming its your code) - not sure that it will do what you want, but might get closer. Beyond that is there any chance you could just write that class in Java?

Comment: I haven't tried these other implementations (I will only if the java 7 switch is not an option). I add the CompileStatic annotation on the AST, but I haven't checked if it was really taken into account.... Will do.

Comment: You are in a tough spot. Yes, you can gain performance by de-groovying down to standard Java, but unfortunately the language does not always give you a direct path to the underlying Java. Good luck. Also, be sure you are applying the CompileStatic to the generated code programmatically, and not just adding it as an annotation to the transformer itself. ;-)

Comment: @cjstehno Indeed, it seems that adding the annotation in my AST does not tell the compiler to statically compile the code. How can I generate statically compiled code in my AST:

final MethodNode method = classNode.addMethod(methodName, Modifier.PUBLIC, ClassHelper.VOID_TYPE, new Parameter[] { attNameParam, valueParam }, ClassNode.EMPTY_ARRAY,
    code);
  method.addAnnotation(new AnnotationNode(compileStaticCN)); //does not seem to be usefull

Comment: You would build up your code nodes and then apply the compile static transformer to the programmatically.

Comment: Indeed, the issue was that the CompileStatic was not applied. Directly applying the StaticCompileTransformation from my AST solved the problem and I am no longer seeing isCase in my VisualVM sampling. At least not high. Thanks @cjstehno for the remark.

Comment: I am wandering why the ASTTransformationCollectorCodeVisitor is not rescanning the tree at each phase, but that would be another question...

Comment: Glad it helped. I have converted this to an answer, if you would like to accept it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the Groovy CompileStatic transformation in your AST, after building your nodes, should cause your generated code to be statically compiled. Be sure that you are doing this programmatically in your code, not by adding the annotation to your transformation class.

In most cases the plain old Java version of code constructs will be more performant than the added Groovy syntax; however, it can be difficult to access the underlying Java constructs in some cases.

This should at least take it one step farther.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not go all the way : applying the CompileStatic was useful as it removed some callXXX calls, but the generated bytecode still uses isCase calls, not the powerful java 7 switch :-(

Comment: I refactored my AST to use if/else statements (and not switch/case). It would have been best to generate the tableswitch, but since we usually have less than 10-20 cases, if/else are efficient enough.